# Using linkbutton with gridview and updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Iam ASP.Net beginner and i have started a project in which i have used a Gridview with linkbuttons in one column fetching data from DB. The idea is that whenever we click the linkbutton a CSS popup window should appear with some textboxes/areas containing information about the subject. I am getting a problem that when i click 1st linkbutton i get information related to first subject and when i click the second linkbutton i am getting the same information again. I dont know what to do to overcome this problem. And also i have noticed that first time the linkbutton2 doesnt work and it work only after opening linkbtn1 details.

Here is the block of Gridview markup code as well as the code which fetch data from database.

ASPX page:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="ddl-pri" Font-Names="Helvetica World"
            Font-Size="15pt" Height="40px" Width="155px" Style="margin-top: -64px; margin-left: 172px; position: absolute;"
            AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="DropDownList"
            DataTextField="Project_Name" DataValueField="Project_Name"
            AppendDataBoundItems="True"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Select</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DropDownList" runat="server"
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PECS %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT [Project Name] AS Project_Name FROM [Project]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <div id="grid">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"
                GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True"
                PageSize="8" OnRowCommand="grdListUsers_RowCommand"
                OnRowDataBound="RowDataBound">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            #
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subject">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Subject").ToString().Shorten(10)%>'
                                CommandName="LinkButton1"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Estimated Start">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Est Start", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Estimated End">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Est End", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Estimated Time">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Estd Time") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Progress" HeaderText="Progress"
                        SortExpression="Progress" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type"
                        SortExpression="Type" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Assigned" HeaderText="Employee Name"
                        SortExpression="Assigned" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Role" HeaderText="Role" SortExpression="Role" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="Phone" />
                </Columns>
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"
                    Font-Names="NewsGoth BT" Font-Size="13.38pt" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="GridViewSource1" runat="server"
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PECS %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT Task.Subject, Task.[Est Start], Task.[Est End], Task.[Estd Time], Task.Progress, Task.Type, Task.Assigned, Task.[Project Name], Employee.Role, Employee.Email, Employee.Phone FROM Task INNER JOIN Employee ON Task.Assigned = Employee.Name WHERE (Task.[Project Name] = 'Temp')"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

C# code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.RegisterPostBackControl();
    string ddl = DropDownList1.Text;
    AddProjBut.Style.Add("display", "none");

    if (Session["UserName"] != null)
    {
        Userlbl.Text = Session["UserName"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Content/Intro.aspx");
    }

    Calendar1.Style.Add("position", "absolute");
    Calendar2.Style.Add("position", "absolute");
    Calendar3.Style.Add("position", "absolute");
    Calendar4.Style.Add("position", "absolute");

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //  AddProjBut.Style.Add("display", "none");
        Calendar1.Visible = false;
        Calendar2.Visible = false;
        Calendar3.Visible = false;
        Calendar4.Visible = false;
        TextBox1.Text = "";
        TextBox2.Text = "";
        EstdStart.Text = "";
        EstdEnd.Text = "";
        Hours.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        style();
    }
}

private void RegisterPostBackControl()
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        LinkButton lnkFull = row.FindControl("LinkButton1") as LinkButton;
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(lnkFull);
    }
}

protected void grdListUsers_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.CommandName == "LinkButton1")
    {
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;

        LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)row.FindControl("LinkButton1");

        if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                con.Open(); cmd.Connection = con;

                if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex > 0)
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Subject, [Task Desc], [Est Start], [Est End], [Estd Time], Progress, Type, Assigned FROM Task WHERE (Subject = @txt)";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txt", lb.Text);

                    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            TextBox3.Text = rdr["Subject"].ToString();
                            TextBox4.Text = rdr["Task Desc"].ToString();
                            TEstsStart.Text = rdr["Est Start"].ToString();
                            TEstdEnd.Text = rdr["Est End"].ToString();
                            TaskHours.Text = rdr["Estd Time"].ToString();
                            Progress.Text = rdr["Progress"].ToString();
                            DropDownList2.Text = rdr["Type"].ToString();
                            Assign.Text = rdr["Assigned"].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lblmsg.Visible = true;
                    lblmsg.Text = "Select Some Value";
                    style();
                }
            }
        }
        else { style(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is in your Page_Load method?

Comment: Please post the `GridView` markup code where you define the structure of  each grid row. Also, the binding code and the page event it is happening in would be helpful.

Comment: So I see an extension method of `Shorten`, which I presume truncates the `Subject` data value to only be 10 characters for display on the link button, correct? If so, then what is the value of the first subject button you click and the second subject button you click? I am confused as to why you are truncating the value of subject to fit on a button and then using that as the `WHERE` clause of your retrieval of data for the popup display.

Answer (score 0):

Its happening because you have bound the same column(column you've bound with 1st link button) to 2nd link button. Bind separate column to 2nd link button. Hope my answer has helped you.

Comment: if what i understand is right u r suggesting to create seperate column for othr lnkbtn, i hav posted markup code and also i inserted one lnkbtn to call data from DB , what difference does it make creating another column.
if iam wrong pls give me some more explanation

Comment: @Uday Desiraju :Remove 'shorten(10)' from your code. Add debug point at method- 'grdListUsers_RowCommand()' and see what the value you are getting in your select query of the variable '@txt'. You are facing problem may be due to in your select query 'where' clause is not getting the subject name as you've truncated it using 'shorten(10)'.

Comment: @Uday Desiraju: So please mark my answer as- "This answer is useful".